# JQuery can't make a global string in two values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i cant manage to get the "length" value to work when the second button is pressed.
So what the first button will do is that it will print out if the length of the name is greater or equal to 5, or less than 5. And when I press the other button it will give me the length of the name, and I cant make it to work, plz help me! And Im just a learning programmer so if you could explain just a bit what is wrong, or what i should, that would be great!Thanks in advance!

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HelloWorld</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-
1.8.1.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="name">Please enter your name: </label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="button" value="Check" id="check">
<br /><br />
<label for="check">So, how long is my name?: </label>
<input type="button" id="length" value="How Long?" name="check">

<script type="text/javascript">




$("#check").click(function (length){
 var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
 console.log("Variable 'name' is created");
 var length = name.length;
 console.log("We have found the length");

 if (length >= 5){
  alert("Your name is greater or equal to 5");
  console.log("Printed >= 5");
 }else{
  alert("Your name is less than 5");
  console.log("Printed < 4");
 }
});

$("#length").click(function(length){
 alert(length);
});

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `var` creates a local  variable. To create a global, use `window.length = name.length`. The `window` is the global object. Any properties added to it show up as global variables.

Comment: @squint `var` creates a variable, in *this* case scoped to the function, because that's the only other scope other than the global scope.

Comment: The first argument passed to a `.click` handler is an `Event`, not whatever you assume it is in the code above

Comment: The argument `length` in the second handler is actually the Event object, which is automatically passed to event handlers. There's no way to pass values within argument part of a function expression, they just represent names of the arguments. Values are passed when you're invoking a function, within parenthesis _after_ a function name.

Comment: Did what u told me, but it doesent seem to work. When I press the other button i get [object Object].Thanks for the tip

Comment: So how exactly should my program look like? If you could post an answer

Comment: @DaveNewton: "Local" isn't a spec term AFAIK. It's just a way of saying that it's constrained to the nearest enclosing variable scope. You can use `var` in the global environment too, and it'll create a new variable that is local to that environment, which happens to be global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define length at the top of the script block so it will always be available.

This code should work. Also nice I took out the length variables you were passing into the click functions.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var length;


$("#check").click(function (){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    console.log("Variable 'name' is created");
    length = name.length;
    console.log("We have found the length");

    if (length >= 5){
        alert("Your name is greater or equal to 5");
        console.log("Printed >= 5");
    }else{
        alert("Your name is less than 5");
        console.log("Printed < 4");
    }
});

$("#length").click(function(){
    alert(length);
});

</script>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gzgjbbk/)

Comment: It worked for me in chrome. what browser are you using? Are you saying the fiddle doesnt work?

Comment: Soz, it seems to be working now. Thanks for the tip and the reply. Sorry again